# Make: Setting target-specific variables in static pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a Makefile using static pattern rules and I want for each element of TARGETS a variable assigned to the current target name (here the stem '%').

```
TARGETS = a b c d

all : $(TARGETS)
$(TARGETS) : % : DIR = %
$(TARGETS) : % : %_setup build

a_setup :
 code for a
b_setup :
 code for b
...
build
 code using "DIR = XX" previously configured
```

but gnumake complains about the target-specific variable DIR:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'DIR', needed by 'a'
```

Is it possible to mix static pattern rules and variable assignation? Thanks!

Comment: in this specific case you can use `TARGET: DIR=$@`.

Comment: You never need to do this.  A requirement of a static pattern rule is that you have a list of targets... so you can always just use normal target-specific variables with that list of targets.

Answer (score 3):

According to the GNU make manual you can't do it like that. However, you can use `$@`. In you example you can directly assign `DIR=$@` but more generally you can use `$@` in combination with `patsubst`:

```
TARGETS = a b c d
all : $(TARGETS)
$(TARGETS) : DIR = $(patsubst %,%,$@)
$(TARGETS) : % : %_setup build
        echo $@: DIR:$(DIR)
%_setup :
        echo $@
build:
        echo $@
```

Comment: `Makefile:5: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.` My make is `GNU Make 4.3+dbg-1.`