# Problems with make pattern

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to create a symbolic-link between index.html -> README.html. But, I can't figure out why is not matching.

```
ADOC_FILES := $(wildcard ./*.adoc ./folder/*.adoc ./folder2/*.adoc)
HTML_FILES := $(patsubst ./%.adoc,./%.html,$(ADOC_FILES))

./%.html: ./%.adoc
    @echo HTML $@
    @asciidoctor $< -b html5 -o $@ $<

%/README.html: $(filter-out %/README\.html,$(HTML_FILES)) | $(patsubst %\,%,)
    @echo "HTML-INDEX $@ -> $(dir $@)index.html"
    ${Q}cd $(dir $@) && ln -fs README.html index.html

html: $(HTML_FILES)

clean:
    @echo CLEAN $(HTML_FILES)
    @rm -f $(HTML_FILES)
```

The current output.

```
[jpereira@sugarloaf make]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jpereira  staff  396 Jul 24 12:03 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 jpereira  staff    0 Jul 24 11:44 README.adoc
-rw-r--r--  1 jpereira  staff    0 Jul 24 11:44 hello.adoc
-rw-r--r--  1 jpereira  staff    0 Jul 24 11:44 main.adoc
-rw-r--r--  1 jpereira  staff    0 Jul 24 11:44 test.adoc
[jpereira@sugarloaf make]$ make
HTML README.html
HTML hello.html
HTML main.html
HTML test.html
[jpereira@sugarloaf make]$
```

Comment: What you want to do is to call the target `%/README.html` in the same time as `./%.html` ?

Comment: That is the idea. I want to run `make clean html` and execute the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The most fundamental problem here is with `make`'s strategy for choosing the default target to build when you do not specify one to it on the command line (which you don't): it selects the first target appearing in your file that does not begin with a '.'.  In combination with that, you need to understand that pattern rules don't specify any targets (patterns can be *matched* to targets, but they do not *specify* targets).  This is why it is common for makefiles to have an `all` target as the first one.

In your case, the default target is `html`, and accordingly, `make` first builds any missing or out-of-date prerequisites from among `$(HTML_FILES)`, and then ... does nothing else, because there is no recipe for building `html` itself (so it should be marked `.PHONY`).  That's exactly what you see.

Secondarily, but importantly, if you want `make` to create a file named `index.html`, then your makefile should provide a rule that names that file as a target and contains a recipe for building it.

Putting that together, you get something like this:

```
ADOC_FILES   := $(wildcard ./*.adoc ./folder/*.adoc ./folder2/*.adoc)
HTML_FILES   := $(patsubst ./%.adoc,./%.html,$(ADOC_FILES))
README_FILES := $(filter %/README.html,$(HTML_FILES))
INDEX_FILES  := $(patsubst %/README.html,%/index.html,$(README_FILES))
HTML_FILES   := $(filter-out $(INDEX_FILES),$(HTML_FILES))

all: html $(INDEX_FILES)

# Carried over from the original
html: $(HTML_FILES)

$(HTML_FILES): ./%.html: ./%.adoc
    @echo HTML $@
    @asciidoctor $< -b html5 -o $@ $<

# It's not necessary to create the link target before the link, and the
# working directory does not affect the interpretation of relative symlinks
$(INDEX_FILES):
    @echo "HTML-INDEX $(D@)/README.html -> $@"
    ln -s README.html $@

# Note: does not clean up $(INDEX_FILES), per the original
clean:
    @echo CLEAN $(HTML_FILES)
    @rm -f $(HTML_FILES)

# Defined targets whose names do not designate a real file to build should
# be marked phony:
.PHONY: all clean html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a special target that will do a job, in your case create the symlink, and then add it to the prerequisite list.

```
# Find all adoc files
ADOC_FILES := $(shell find -name '*.adoc')
HTML_FILES := $(patsubst %.adoc,%.html,$(ADOC_FILES))
# Get all README files
READMES := $(filter %README.html,$(HTML_FILES))

# Special rule that has other needs
# Call the rule do_link_README/ appended to the real README path
$(READMES): %: do_link_README/%

.PHONY: all
all: $(HTML_FILES)
    @echo Done

# The html rule just defines a dependency on a second rule that does the real job
%.html: %.ascii
    @true

# Rule used to be the dependency of do_link_README
%.ascii: %.adoc
    @echo "ASCII $@"

# Make it depends on some prerequisites, so it is done after them
# % matches the path of the README file, without the extension, so I can specify
# the right .ascii dependency
do_link_README/%.html: %.ascii
# Retrieve Path from the stem (% in target, $* in recipe)
    $(eval README_P=$(patsubst %README,%,$*))
    @echo "-----------> ln -fs $*.ascii $(README_P)index.html"
```

Which gives :

```sh
$ find
.
./README.adoc
./folder1
./folder1/README.adoc
./folder1/hello.adoc
./folder1/main.adoc
./folder1/test.adoc
./folder3
./folder3/README.adoc
./folder3/hello.adoc
./folder3/main.adoc
./folder3/test.adoc
./hello.adoc
./main.adoc
./folder2
./folder2/README.adoc
./folder2/hello.adoc
./folder2/main.adoc
./folder2/test.adoc
./test.adoc
./Makefile
$ make all -j5
ASCII README.ascii
ASCII folder1/README.ascii
ASCII folder1/hello.ascii
ASCII folder1/main.ascii
ASCII folder1/test.ascii
ASCII folder3/README.ascii
ASCII folder3/hello.ascii
ASCII folder3/main.ascii
ASCII folder3/test.ascii
ASCII hello.ascii
ASCII main.ascii
ASCII folder2/README.ascii
ASCII folder2/hello.ascii
ASCII folder2/main.ascii
ASCII folder2/test.ascii
ASCII test.ascii
-----------> ln -fs README.ascii index.html
-----------> ln -fs folder1/README.ascii folder1/index.html
-----------> ln -fs folder3/README.ascii folder3/index.html
-----------> ln -fs folder2/README.ascii folder2/index.html
Done
```

Please not that I removed `"./"`, I think it's useless here.

#### Edit

After some research, I got help in [this gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) page and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014138/5868851)

Comment: The point is because the link should be called after the process the `%.html: ./%.adoc` and might exist `README.html` in subfolders.

Comment: "_In make you can't define several behavior for a same target_". Well, this is not entirely true in GNU make. See the [double-colon rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for the link, I updated my answer to remove this part

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your `%/README.html` rule (and I suspect that you did not fully understand how pre-requisites are expanded by make) but it apparently produces `index.html`, not `README.html`. So, why do you use `%/README.html` as the target of your rule. Why don't you use `%/index.html`? Something like:

```
ADOC_FILES   := $(wildcard ./*.adoc ./folder/*.adoc ./folder2/*.adoc)
HTML_FILES   := $(patsubst ./%.adoc,./%.html,$(ADOC_FILES))
README_FILES := $(filter %/README.html,$(HTML_FILES))
INDEX_FILES  := $(patsubst %/README.html,%/index.html,$(README_FILES))
HTML_FILES   := $(filter-out $(INDEX_FILES),$(HTML_FILES))

$(HTML_FILES): ./%.html: ./%.adoc
    @echo HTML $@
    @asciidoctor $< -b html5 -o $@ $<

$(INDEX_FILES): %/index.html: $(HTML_FILES)
    @echo "HTML-INDEX $(D@)/README.html -> $(@D)/index.html"
    ${Q}cd $(@D) && ln -fs README.html index.html

html: $(HTML_FILES)

clean:
    @echo CLEAN $(HTML_FILES)
    @rm -f $(HTML_FILES)
```